# Python Variables and Equations

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm pretty new to Python and coding in general, however I was messign around with some bisection stuff and I came across a problem. I have this code:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 0

fa = a**3-a-2
fb = b**3-b-2
fc = c**3-c-2

c += 2
print(fc)
```

The problem is that when I run it, the 'c' variable changes but 'fc' stays the same and outputs -2, when it should output 4 instead. No matter what I've tried, fc alwas stays the same and updating c does nothing to change fc, even though I believe it should?

Comment: Why do you believe `fc` would change? The variable stores the *outcome* of the expression, not the expression itself.

Comment: Take a look at: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions or https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions for python 3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python stores the *outcome* of the expressions in `fa`, `fb` and `fc`, not the expressions themselves:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> c = 0
>>> fa = a**3-a-2
>>> fb = b**3-b-2
>>> fc = c**3-c-2
>>> fa
-2
>>> fb
4
>>> fc
-2
>>> type(fc)
<class 'int'>
```

If you wanted to re-run an expression for changing variables, create *functions*. For a single expression, you can create a function object by using a [`lambda` expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

```
fa = lambda: a**3-a-2
fb = lambda: b**3-b-2
fc = lambda: c**3-c-2
```

These 3 functions expect `a`, `b` and `c` to exist in their parent scope. Now changing `c` and then *calling* the function will re-run the expression:

```
c += 2
print(fc())  # note the (), calling the function
```

Demo:

```
>>> fa = lambda: a**3-a-2
>>> fb = lambda: b**3-b-2
>>> fc = lambda: c**3-c-2
>>> fa
<function <lambda> at 0x10979dd90>
>>> fb
<function <lambda> at 0x1097b1e18>
>>> fc
<function <lambda> at 0x1097b1ea0>
>>> fc()  # calling a function executes the expression, each time
-2
>>> c += 2
>>> fc()
4
```